# How to compare Arrays of two Graphs for the Shape or Pattern?

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

How do I compare two graphs for the similarity with each other. Basically I would like to compare the pattern of two graphs and come up with a percentage of how close the two graphs are. I am trying to do this in Javascript where I have got two data arrays based on which graphs are drawn. Can somebody please guide me to any algorithm or Javascript code snippet to do that?

Comment: Can you provide an example of two arrays you'd like to compare?

Comment: arr=[0,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,6,14,39,40,45,71,80,84,90,88,73,44,29,23,18,14,12,11,14,15,34,24,10,8,7,6,4,4,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,4,31,62,73,72,54,21,12,13,23,16,11,9,5,5,5,4,4,3,5,6,6,4,4,3,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,5,43,43,44,76,84,92,81,56,38,27,22,16,13,14,16,16]                                                               

arr1=9,21,19,22,27,27,27,23,24,22,24,24,28,38,72,64,49,62,63,69,73,68,54,36,34,30,26,25,23,27,28,25,30,37,41,28,23,23,23,24,24,23,26,23,24,22,21,21,20,23,23,25,24,23,24,23,25,24,23,23,27,25,26,26,28,58,69,49,48,64,]

Comment: The first array has 122 elements, the second has only 70.  Not sure the best way to compare the two.